# IHostingEnvironment for testing

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to use the unit test project in *ABP 2.0.2* and I get the following error when I run the selected test **GetUsers_Test()**.

```
Message: Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException : Can't create component 'imfundoplatform.imfundoplatformCoreModule' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'imfundoplatform.imfundoplatformCoreModule' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' which was not registered.
```

The constructor for my **Core** module:

```
public imfundoplatformCoreModule(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    _appConfiguration = AppConfigurations.Get(env.ContentRootPath, env.EnvironmentName, env.IsDevelopment());
}
```

I cannot figure out how to pass this to the module or get unit tests working. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot inject *IHostingEnvironment* ... To get the content root path use;

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
```

Comment: But then I still need to remove IHostingEnvironment from the template-created constructor. Would my Core module still even work?

Comment: there's no IHostingEnvironment in the source. See the source https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/AbpProjectNameCoreModule.cs

Comment: This won't help if one wants to test AppServices which depend on IHostingEnvironment. A different solution is to mock IHostingEnvironment.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your design. AppServices are application logic codes and they are not part of Web layer. So if you need some root path you have to send this as a parameter from the running platform. (eg: If you are consuming AppServices from a Xamarin platform so HostingEnvironment doesn't make sense)

Answer (score 8):

You *can* inject IHostingEnvironment. But you will have to do it in some weird ways:

First create a mock IHostingEnvrionment class like this (adjust it to your needs):

```
public class MockHostingEnvironment : IHostingEnvironment, ISingletonDependency
{
    public string EnvironmentName
    {
        get => throw new NotImplementedException();
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ApplicationName
    {
        get => throw new NotImplementedException();
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public string WebRootPath { get; set; } = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "wwwroot");
    public IFileProvider WebRootFileProvider
    {
        get => throw new NotImplementedException();
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string ContentRootPath { get; set; } = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

    public IFileProvider ContentRootFileProvider
    {
        get => throw new NotImplementedException();
        set => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

After that add this to your `Initialize()` of your TestModule:

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    (...)
    IocManager.Register<IHostingEnvironment, MockHostingEnvironment>(DependencyLifeStyle.Singleton);
}
```

Note that using Environment.CurrentDirectory is a very bad way of doing it. It might point to a different directory depending on your CI, your test runner, your testing framework etc.

You should *only* use this MockHostingEnvironment if you use services in your test which need the IHostingEnvironment.

Comment: This was useful for me when I had multiple db contexts setup. With the main context only in use this wasn't required. However I had a further name with EnvironmentName. This worked 
`public string EnvironmentName { get; set; } = "TestEnvironment";`